# Show $\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k}{k}\frac{a-k}{a+k}=\binom{a+n}{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How it can be shown that:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k}{k}\frac{a-k}{a+k}=\binom{a+n}{n}$$

Where $a \ne 0$

---

My try:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k}{k}\frac{a-k}{a+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k}{a}\frac{a-k}{a+k}$$

$$=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}\left(a-k \right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}-\frac{1}{a}\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}k }$$

On the other hand:

$$\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(a+k-1\right)2^{n-k}\binom{a+k-2}{k-1}  $$

But computing these expressions takes much time and I think there should be a better way, but I cannot find that way.

Please if it's possible, then do the proof using elementary ways.

Comment: You can try using Mathematical Induction unless of course you don't know the result before hand.

Comment: @Jamal, that's exactly the basic problem I have with induction, I want to know the idea behind this identity , but induction just proves and does not tell us about that idea.

Comment: Do you require a combinatorial proof?

Comment: @ h-squared,a combinatorial proof would be good,but first I really like to know the algebraic one.

Answer (score 2):

I know you would prefer a combinatorial proof and thinks that induction does not tell us anything, but since you would like to know an algebraic proof, I'll just include an inductive proof for completion's sake.

Base case $n = 0$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^0 2^{-k}{a + k \choose k}\frac{a - k}{a + k} = 2^0 {a \choose 0}\frac{a}{a} = 1 = {a \choose 0}
$$
Assume true for $n = m$. For $n = m+1$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} 2^{m+1-k}{a + k \choose k}\frac{a - k}{a + k} &= 2\sum_{k=0}^m, 2^{m-k}{a + k \choose k}\frac{a - k}{a + k} + {a + m + 1 \choose m + 1}\frac{a - m - 1}{a + m + 1} \\
&= 2{a + m \choose m} + {a + m + 1 \choose m + 1}\left(\frac{a - m - 1}{a + m + 1}\right) \\
&= 2\left(\frac{m + 1}{a + m + 1}\right){a + m + 1 \choose m + 1} + \left(\frac{a - m - 1}{a + m + 1}\right) {a + m + 1 \choose m + 1} \\
&= \left(\frac{a - m - 1 + 2(m + 1)}{a + m + 1}\right) {a + m + 1 \choose m + 1} \\
&= {a + m + 1 \choose m + 1}
\end{align*}
This completes the induction.

Comment: @ Clement Yung,thank you so much for your consideration

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algebric proof :

Let $ a $ be a real, let's define the function $ f_{a} $ as follows : $$ \left(\forall x\in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[\right),\ f_{a}\left(x\right)=\displaystyle\frac{1-2x}{\left(1-x\right)^{a+1}} $$

know : \begin{aligned} \left(\forall x\in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[\right),\ f_{a}\left(x\right)&=\displaystyle\frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)^{a}}-\displaystyle\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{a+1}}\\ &=2\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-a}{n}x^{n}}-\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-a-1}{n}x^{n}} \end{aligned}
Observe that forall $ \left(x,n\right)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N} $ :
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(-1\right)^{n}\binom{-x}{n}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-x-k\right)}=\frac{1}{n!}\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(x+k\right)}=\frac{1}{n!}\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(x+n-1-k\right)}=\binom{x+n-1}{n} $

Thus, \begin{aligned}\left(\forall x\in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[\right),\ f_{a}\left(x\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(2\displaystyle\binom{a+n-1}{n}+\displaystyle\binom{a+n}{n}\right)x^{n}}\end{aligned}

Since $ \binom{a+n-1}{n}=\frac{a}{a+n}\binom{a+n}{n} $, we get, \begin{aligned}\left(\forall x\in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[\right),\ f_{a}\left(x\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{a-n}{a+n}\displaystyle\binom{a+n}{n}x^{n}}\end{aligned}

Observe $ \left(\forall x\in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[\right),\ \frac{f_{a}\left(x\right)}{1-2x}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{a+1}} $, meaning that forall $ x \in\left]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right[ $, \begin{aligned} \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{a-n}{a+n}\displaystyle\binom{a+n}{n}x^{n}}\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{2^{n}x^{n}}\right)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-a-1}{n}x^{n}} \\ \iff \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2^{n-k}\displaystyle\binom{a+k}{k}\displaystyle\frac{a-k}{a+k}}\right)x^{n}}&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\binom{a+n}{n}x^{n}}\end{aligned}
Which leads to the following : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2^{n-k}\displaystyle\binom{a+k}{k}\displaystyle\frac{a-k}{a+k}}=\displaystyle\binom{a+n}{n} $$

Comment: your proof is fantastic and amazing. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: thank you so much.